# Keep receiving Sorry, it is not possible to delete all non-frozen rows

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script on Google Apps Script, the script is working ok but I keep receiving

> Sorry, it is not possible to delete all non-frozen rows line 70

Here is related part of the code:

```
  //start delete rows
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i+1 <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i+1];
    if (row > '') { // This searches all cells in columns A (change to row[1] for columns B and so on) 
  and deletes row if cell is empty or has value 'delete'.
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  };
  //end delete rows

  function onOpen() {  
  var menu = [    
    { name: "? Help and Support »",    functionName: "help"},
    null,
    { name: "Step 1: Authorize",   functionName: "init"      },
    { name: "Step 2: Schedule Reports", functionName: "configure" },
    null,
    { name: "? Uninstall (Stop)",    functionName: "reset"     },
    null
  ];  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .addMenu("? Drive Activity Report", menu);
  }

  function help() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('help')
  .setTitle("Google Scripts Support")
  .setWidth(400)
  .setHeight(160);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.show(html);
  }
```

I have added a picture, I don't have any lines left as they are all deleted after the emails are sent, this all works except that I receive a daily report regarding non frozen rows.
Is the report perhaps complaining because the last row is blank and cannot be frozen or deleted?
[image of spreadsheet as requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj9yb.png)

I am including a copy of the error report I receive each day, regarding non frozen rows, as stated in my last comment, there are no errors in any of the script logs.[image of daily report on non frozen rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de15Q.png)

The answer seems to be that the rows have to be frozen before delete, I have added the freeze code but I am not sure if this is now correct

```
//start delete rows
function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
     var numRowsFr = 1;
     sheet.setFrozenRows(numRowsFr);
  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[0] == 'delete' || row[0] == '') { // This searches all cells in columns A (change to row[1] for columns B and so on) and deletes row if cell is empty or has value 'delete'.
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};

//end delete rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Deleting Rows**

```
function deletingRows() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var v=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var d=0;
  v.forEach(function(r,i,a){if(!r[0] || r[0]=='delete'){sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++)}}); 
}
```

Comment: I made a small change to it.  I wasn't deleting the blanks

Comment: No, I just received exactly the same report regarding, "Sorry, it is not possible to delete all non-frozen rows line 70"  I am at a loss on this one, any further suggestions please

Comment: I tried it with frozen rows and did see any problem so I'd have to know more about  the state of your spreadsheet perhaps you can explain that further and provide an image.

Comment: When I check the Stackdriver Error Reporting log there are no errors and everything completed correctly, the same is true for the trigger log.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by moving delete rows to the top of the script after declarations, but before the email formation and send.

Comment: Thank you Vishal Pawar, I have done this and I thought it was fixed, but I still receive this 'non-frozen rows report', then I removed the delete rows loop altogether and I still receive the report? I cannot resolve this, please help

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that my spreadsheet had no lines, so the script was trying to delete a blank line.

I simply added a line in position 1 and the problem is solved.